# I have a EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION with Swift 2.1.1 on Playground and need help to identify it

Tags: arrays, swift, swift2, swift-playground

Here is my playground code:

```
import UIKit

class CellularAutomata{

    var array = Array(count:1, repeatedValue:Array(count: 1, repeatedValue: Bool()))
    var chanceToStartAlive = 0.45
    var width = 384
    var height = 384

    init(){
        self.array = Array(count:self.width, repeatedValue:Array(count: self.height, repeatedValue: Bool()))
        initialise()
    }
    init(chanceToStartAlive chance: Double){
        chanceToStartAlive = chance
        self.array = Array(count:self.width, repeatedValue:Array(count: self.height, repeatedValue: Bool()))
        initialise()
    }
    init(chanceToStartAlive chance: Double, width columns: Int, height rows: Int){
        chanceToStartAlive = chance
        self.array = Array(count:columns, repeatedValue:Array(count: rows , repeatedValue: Bool()))
        initialise()
    }

    func initialise(){
        for index in 0...array.count{
            for jndex in 0...array[index].count{
                if(randomCGDouble() < self.chanceToStartAlive){
                    array[index][jndex] = true
                }
            }
        }
    }

    func randomCGDouble() -> Double {
        return Double(arc4random()) /  Double(UInt32.max)
    }
}
```

The bad instruction occurs when the initialise() function is called.  I feel like I am overlooking some thing really obvious and I am gonna face-palm when someone explains it to me.

EDIT: Sorry Everyone! I Figured out I did something dumb.  I need to do .count - 1 on the arrays.  Like I said, face palm.  I figured this out once I discovered you can activate console in playground and could finally get some output feedback for the errors.

Comment: Can you post some useful error message? EXC_BAD_INSTRUCTION means something went wrong. Not helpful.

Comment: And how big exactly did you make your array?

Comment: See my edit and luk2302's answer for why this was wrong.  It was such a simple mistake....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to change your `initialise` to

```
func initialise(){
    print(array.count)
    for index in 0..<array.count{
        for jndex in 0..<array[index].count{
            if(randomCGDouble() < self.chanceToStartAlive){
                array[index][jndex] = true
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Note the `0..<array` in the two loops instead of the previous `0...array`. That will prevent the index to get out of bounds.

Note that the array is quite large - try testing it with `width` and `height` of `12` instead.

Comment: Yeah, this would have worked as well, similar to what I did in my edit

Comment: Please avoid C Style for loops are they will be removed from the language. As you can see they are error prone.

Comment: @ tmpz : According to this: https://github.com/apple/swift-evolution/blob/master/proposals/0007-remove-c-style-for-loops.md For-in loops will be kept.  The are removing stuff that looks like: for var i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ {
    print(i)
}

Comment: My bad I was misguided.